# Create new "screens" dynamically

Tags: android, android-activity

I have an application that gets information from a database and it creates ImageButtons dynamically. What I want is, when I click a dynamically created ImageButton, I want it to make a search in my database (which I know how to do) and then create a new activity (or screen) with new ImageButtons created dynamically, too.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot create activities without declaring them in the manifest file. You can either call setContentView after creating the new layout(I do not recomend this.).

Or use the viewflipper and add the the different layouts as childs to it. So you can use the viewflipper to switch between layouts.

Comment: Hello again @blessenm. Well... I followed your suggestion and it worked great. However I am having another problem. Can you help me, please? I posted a separated thread... I didn't want to confuse anyone else. The new problem is related to ViewFlipper, I guess. Please take a look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8059670/viewflipper-messed-with-my-layouts. Your help is very much appreciated! =)

Answer (score 0):

Best option is to read the android developer documentation on how [Intents](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/intents/intents-filters.html) can be used to launch  a New Activity

```
An Intent object is passed to Context.startActivity() or 
Activity.startActivityForResult() to launch an activity or 
get an existing activity to do something new. 
(It can also be passed to Activity.setResult() to return 
information to the activity that called startActivityForResult().)
```

Comment: Hello @Rajdeep Dua as I said above I don't want to launch an activity or get an existing activity to do something new. All activities must be in AndroidManifest.xml, as far as I can tell... what I need is to CREATE new activities, screens or views... I don't know what is the best name/solution for this. Should I create them dinamically and then just setContentView?

Answer (score 0):

```
 ImageButton imagebutton=new ImageButton(this);
 imagebutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
             getDataFromDataBase();//In this method you get data from database
             Intent intent=new Intent(currentactivity.this,newactivity.class);//start new screen.. in this you can create imagebutton dynamically
             startActivity(intent);
          finish(); 

        }

});
```

Comment: Hello @deepa... thank you for your help... it seems it will work... however how do I tie my created layout to this newly created activity? Won't this activity "newactivity.class have to be in AndroidManifest.xml?

Answer (score 0):

just execute the code that you have inside your onCreate (wrap it in an init(Params param) method), and call that inside your onClickListener. of course exclude the setContentView and findViewById's.